# Tor downloads files in the background, then asks for permission

Tags: plugin, update

After the recent updates, when i click download for any file, it takes a lot of time to show the message with 'download now' and 'cancel' options...but after clicking 'download now' and choosing the file location, it is seen that the download is completed in no time...

After few more trials I came to know that the files are downloaded in background before asking for permission to store the downloaded file.

My friends are also having such problems. But we don't have any knowledge on programming or how to work or build tor etc..

We just use tor for some of our specific needs as most of the websites are blocked in our university.

So if someone can help us with this issue,we would be very grateful.
I once tried DownThemAll plug-in also,but it could not download a single file. I don't know if it also requires any configurations or not.

Answer (score 2):

This is the 'pre-fetch' feature in Firefox, which starts downloads in the background for you - you see it as 'instant' because it already downloaded the file before you confirm the download.

You can disable it like this:

1) Type `about:config` in your Firefox address bar and press Enter.

2) Type `network.prefetch-next` in filter text box.

3) Change the value to false

Even though it pre-fetches the file - it's still routed through Tor.